# pythonw - Unable to import most if not all site-packages and even some builtin modules

Tags: python, import, python-3.6

I've started playing around with pygame and pythonw recently, however whenever I attempt to import a majority of modules `pythonw` either imports incomplete modules or fails to import entirely. 
All of the importing errors involve a `Expected in: Flat Namespace`
error with one of the many .so files in my conda3 python directory, which led me to believe that they were being loaded incorrectly by python or that they were broken; however, **the modules all imported correctly in regular python**.

I've ruled out the pythonw being located in a directory with nonexistent modules, as running sys.path in python and pythonw returns the same list.

Example of error, with the default-loaded `help()` command in Python(w) idle:

```py
>>> help()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_sitebuiltins.py", line 102, in __call__
    import pydoc
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pydoc.py", line 63, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/platform.py", line 116, in <module>
    import sys, os, re, subprocess
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __Py_set_inheritable_async_safe
  Expected in: flat namespace
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

In the case of pygame, modules such as `font` are loaded incorrectly and instead replaced with pygame.MissingModule objects

```py
>>> pygame
<module 'pygame' from '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py'>
>>> pygame.font
<pygame.MissingModule object at 0x10e8b5400>
>>>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDBrB.jpg

Comment: It might be, there is a mixup with multiple installed python versions.

if you open a cmd window and just type py.exe
and then `import sys ; print(sys.executable, sys.version_info)`
What output do you get?

Is it the same you get if typing the import / print in python idle?

Please share the output of the import/print from within py.exe and from within python idle?

Comment: Same in both versions. I don't think the versions are mixed up, I think it's an issue with my pythonw. Both sys prints (regular python, pythonw) return `/anaconda3/bin/python sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: check also the output of
`import sys ; print("\n",join(sys.path))`

Comment: Nothing too out of the ordinary seems to be happening I think... Both look like this ```/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.3b1-py3.6.egg```

Comment: Exactly the same?
Not even one line or one character of difference? or lines in a different order?

Comment: Eyup. I'll edit the post to show some sample images

Comment: There most be some tiny difference, that explains all. If no difference is found it could be a corrupt executable, but for the time being Id suggest to still look for other explanations.
Could you please show the output of following commands.

`import os ; print(os.getcwd())`

and 

`import glob ; print(" ".join(glob.glob("*")))`

and

`import os ; print(os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY+PATH"))`